# Is there a data race on packaged task arguments?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, future, packaged-task

A thread is created via a packaged task and a `std::vector` is returned.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <future>
#include <thread>
#include <vector>

std::vector<int> func(int &arg)
{
    std::vector<int> v = {1,2,3,4};

    arg = 10;

    return v;
}

int main()
{
    std::packaged_task<std::vector<int>(int &)> pt{func};
    auto fut = pt.get_future();

    int arg = 0;
    std::thread thr{std::move(pt), std::ref(arg)};

    auto vec = fut.get();

    std::cout << arg << std::endl;  // data race here ?

    thr.join();
}
```

The `std::future` guarantees that the vector is synchronized with the `main` thread (before `join`),
but I am not sure about the status of the packaged task argument (which is passed by reference).

So the question is whether there is a data race on `arg` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
int arg=0;
```

this *happens-before* we start the thread `thr`, as it is *sequenced-before* it.

```
arg = 10;
```

this *happens-before* `vec` is initialized, due to the `.get()` call:

```
auto vec=fut.get();
```

which is *sequenced-before*

```
std::cout << arg << std::endl;
```

so I see no data race here.

While not authortative, [cpp reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/promise) claims:

> The promise is the "push" end of the promise-future communication channel: the operation that stores a value in the shared state synchronizes-with (as defined in std::memory_order) the successful return from any function that is waiting on the shared state (such as std::future::get).

there are similar words for `std::async` as well.  I believe a similar guarantee holds for `packaged_task`; it is intended to be used as a primitive to help implement your own `std::async` like behaviour after all.